# Delete row not working in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I'm creating a component in joomla and I'm having some problems using the database, specifically to delete rows. The code below is what I'm using

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();                       
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // delete if this date already exists for this user
    $conditions = array(
        $db->quoteName('userid') . '='.$array['userid'], 
        $db->quoteName('date') . '='.$date
    );

    $query->delete($db->quoteName('#__timereport_schedule'));
    $query->where($conditions);         
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->execute();
```

So what I'm trying to do here is delete the rows that match the given userid and date, fairly simple. However it ends up not affecting the database. I know the variables `$array['userid']` and `$date` are correct because the same are used later in the same function to do a insert (it's supposed to delete the record if it exists and make a new one) and the insert works fine which means I end up with duplicate entries.

example row that was succesfully inserted:

(`userid`, `date`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `id`, `enddate`, `leave`, `days`) 
VALUES 
(456, '2013-01-01', '08:00:00', '16:00:00', 448, '2013-01-01', '3', '["Tue"]')

with:

```
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $columns = array('userid', 'date', 'starttime', 'endtime', 'id', 'leave');

    $values = array("'".$array['userid']."'", "'".$date."'", "'".$array['starttime']."'", "'".$array['endtime']."'", "'null'", "'".$array['leave']."'");

    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__timereport_schedule'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    try {
        $result = $db->execute();            
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
```

What am I missing? I followed the http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Deleting_a_Record example to create this query.

Comment: Where do you have $array['userid'] and $date defined? It's the only thing it looks like may be missing in your query, thus it may result in error, because those seem not be defined/declared.

Comment: Mario, they are declared in the function call:
public function queries($date, $array) {

the function is called with:
 public function bind($array, $ignore = '') {
        $dt = new DateTime($array['date']);
        $date = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
        $this->queries($date, $array);
}

which is all part of the following class:
class TimereportTableschema extends JTable {
..}

however I know the array and date variables are declared as they are later successfully used in an insert query in the same function which results in duplicates since the delete query does not affect the database.

Comment: At the end, add `echo $query;`. This should print to the screen the SQL query that is actually being run. Post that so we can see the query, since this will help see what could be wrong. (Though as I type this, I'm guessing that the date needs to be quoted.)

Comment: @David Fritsch As frustrating as it is, you were right about the quotations for the date. Add this as a solution and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, add `echo $query;`. This should print to the screen the SQL query that is actually being run. Post that so we can see the query, since this will help see what could be wrong.

Also, in many cases, Joomla redirects after saves to prevent a page refresh from resubmitting data. So it can be helpful to add an `exit();` statement after the echo to actually see what it is echoing.

(Though as I type this, I'm guessing that the date needs to be quoted.)

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work since I've defined sample date and userid. Also, and most importantly, you should be quoting the data (much more important than the db fields, btw):

```
$array['userid'] = 127;
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// delete if this date already exists for this userv
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('userid') . '='.$db->quote($array['userid']),
    $db->quoteName('date') . '='.$db->quote($date)
);
$query->delete($db->quoteName('#__timereport_schedule'));
$query->where($conditions);
try {
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->execute();
}
catch (RuntimeException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// for testing you can echo the query as
echo $db->replacePrefix($query);
```

If `$array['userid']` is not defined or empty, and `$date` is not defined, the query most certainly would throw an error in this example

Comment: Unfortunatly this dosen't seem to work, I'm redirected with the "saved successfully" message as usual so I don't get any exceptions either..

Comment: Sorry I should definetly have included a db sample. I have edited my question to contain both a row of data and the successful insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code after setQuery

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();
```